# Question about differentiability and sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Given $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ differentiable in $a\in X \cap X'_+  \cap X'_-$.

If $x_n<a<y_n \;\forall n$, and $\lim x_n=\lim y_n=a$, prove that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(a).$$
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Obs: $X$ is the domain of function. $X'_-$ is the set of all accumulation points which are to the left to "a", and "X'_+" the set of accumulation points to right of "a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ is equivalent to the existence of a function $\epsilon(x)$ defined in some neighborhood of $a$ such that
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+(x-a)\epsilon(x)\qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\epsilon (x)=0.
$$
It follows that 
$$
f(y_n)-f(x_n)-f'(a)(y_n-x_n)=(y_n-a)\epsilon(y_n)+(a-x_n)\epsilon(x_n).
$$
Now note that $x_n<a<y_n$ yields $0<y_n-a<y_n-x_n$ and $0<a-x_n<y_n-x_n$, whence
$$
\Big|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}-f'(a)\Big|\leq|\epsilon(y_n)|+|\epsilon(x_n)|.
$$
The result follows.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Walterr You're welcome. Your question was probably downvoted because it does not say what $X,X_+',X_-'$ are. Could you please edit it to precise that?

Comment: It is done, Julien. Thank's.